# angular2 how to get rid of npm dependencies using webjars

Tags: angular, npm, webjars

Angular2 rc.5 is there any way i can get rid of npm dependencies and make them webjars - maven dependencies ?

can i resolve typings dependencies same way ? what about systemconfig.js map which i attached in the last.

Following is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

I have maven plugin to perform install

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>exec-npm-install</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static</workingDirectory>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>install</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>exec-npm-run-tsc</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static</workingDirectory>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>tsc</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and maven eqvivalent dependencies of for angular

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__forms</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__http</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__platform-browser-dynamic</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__router</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-rc.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__router-deprecated</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular__upgrade</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>systemjs</artifactId>
            <version>0.19.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-js</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflect-metadata</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjs</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-beta.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>zone.js</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular2-in-memory-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

following is my systemconfig.js what changes i may have to make it here

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using spring boot I did the following and it is working smooth.
INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Set the base href -->
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"></link>
<base href="/"/>
<title>APP</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>


<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></link>
<script src="webjars/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script> 
<script src="webjars/reflect-metadata/0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>  
<script src="webjars/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>


<script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <app>
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
    </app>
</body>

</html>
```

my systemjs.config.js

```
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'webjars/rxjs/5.0.0-beta.6',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'webjars/angular2-in-memory-web-api/0.0.15',
    '@angular/common':            'webjars/angular__common/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/compiler':           'webjars/angular__compiler/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/forms':            'webjars/angular__forms/0.3.0',
    '@angular/core':             'webjars/angular__core/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/http':            'webjars/angular__http/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'webjars/angular__platform-browser/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'webjars/angular__platform-browser-dynamic/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/router': 'webjars/angular__router/3.0.0-rc.1',
    '@angular/router-deprecated': 'webjars/router-deprecated/2.0.0-rc.2'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
  ];
  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

and in the maven dependencies add the following

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.30</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thats all , no need of bulky node_modules. About typescript compiling I am still working on it

Comment: i could not figure out ts compiling so i can't use it.

Comment: I built my application in eclipse IDE and using a plugin palantir/eclipse-typescript. to compile ts files. I am using webjars only for angular 2 reference.

Comment: here were are talking about having npm dependencies as a webjars and then compile tsc files cause an error. still unresolved.